# How to extract specific string from one column and write into a new column if there's a specific string can be found in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a DataFrame as below. I'd like to extract the monthly cell phone allowance and add it to a new column called "Cell Phone Allowance", if "Cell Phone Allowance" can be found in "Compensation Plan" column. For example, I'd like to extract 160.00 from row#1 and nothing from other rows because they don't contain "Cell Phone Allowance".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Compensation Plan' : ['Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance, 160.00 CAD Monthly Salary - Salary Plan, 115,291.25 Annual',
'Salary - Salary Plan, 123,223.54 Annual Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance, 160.00 CAD Monthly',
' ',
'Salary - Salary Plan, 88,704.18 CAD Annual']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.str.extract`

```py
df['Cell Phone Allowance'] = df['Compensation Plan'].str.extract('Cell Phone Allowance, ([0-9.,]*)')
# or
df['Cell Phone Allowance'] = df['Compensation Plan'].str.extract('Cell Phone Allowance, ([^a-zA-Z]*)')
```

```
print(df)

                                                                              Compensation Plan  \
0  Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance, 160.00 CAD Monthly Salary - Salary Plan, 115,291.25 Annual
1  Salary - Salary Plan, 123,223.54 Annual Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance, 160.00 CAD Monthly
2
3                                                    Salary - Salary Plan, 88,704.18 CAD Annual

  Cell Phone Allowance
0               160.00
1               160.00
2                  NaN
3                  NaN
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.  If the rows like "Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance Tier 1, 160.00 CAD Monthly Salary "  or "Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance Tier 2, 180.00 CAD Monthly Salary ". I just need review it to :

  df['Cell Phone Allowance'] = df['Compensation Plan'].str.extract('Allowance - Cell Phone Allowance - Tier \d, ([0-9.,]*)').  It worked. Thanks.

Comment: @BobXu In this case, you can use `df['Cell Phone Allowance'] = df['Compensation Plan'].str.extract('Cell Phone Allowance[^,]*, ([^a-zA-Z]*)')`.

Comment: @BobXu **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.